# dynamic HLOOKUP in google doc spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-docs

I would like to create a HLOOKUP in google doc spreadsheet:

```
=HLOOKUP(aValue;DEC10!$D$2:$W$3;2;FALSE)
```

I have another cell A16 that contains 'DEC10' (a characters cell)
'DEC10' is here the sheet name of the table in which I want to search.
How can I dynamically create the HLOOKUP using my cell A16?
For instance without editing the HLOOKUP formula I want to be able to change sheet DEC10 into sheet DEC11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works using

> INDIRECT

```
=HLOOKUP(aValue;INDIRECT(A16&"!$D$2:$W$3");2;FALSE)
```